# What happened to this selector syntax in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath, jquery-selectors, combobox

I'm in the middle of fixing a jQuery [plugin](http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/page/jquerycombobox.aspx) that is compatible with jQuery 1.1.3.1 and upgrading it so that it works with jQuery 1.6.2.

It has two CSS selector expressions that I assume are deprecated.

The first expression is:

```
$("li", _dropDownListJQuery).not("ul").not("span").not("[@dataType='optgroup']").each(
```

And it looks like the `@datatype` is no longer supported.

The second expression is:

```
var selectedDropDownListItemJQuery = jQuery("li[@dataValue='" + _originalElementJQuery.val() + "']");
```

Where

```
_originalElementJQuery.val()
```

Returns a stringified integer (e.g. "4").

Again it looks like the `@dataValue` is no longer supported.

Does anyone know any meaning preserving equivalents? Or has this plugin been forked on github?

Comment: I guess that `[@dataType]` is an attr, like `[dataType]` now is.

Comment: Note that the `val` method doesn't return an integer, it returns a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's an [XPath Selector](http://ejohn.org/blog/xpath-css-selectors/). They were deprecated in jQuery 1.2, eliminated in jQuery 1.3 and moved to a [plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-xpath/blob/master/jquery.xpath.js). [See the 1.3 release notes here](http://docs.jquery.com/Release%3ajQuery_1.2). Going forward, jQuery selectors mostly support the CSS-selector style.

`$("li[@dataValue='foo']")` would become `$("li[dataValue='foo']")`

That plugin [jquery.combobox](http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/page/jquerycombobox.aspx) has apparently been abandoned, as there hasn't been any further development.

Edited with BoltClock's correction.

Comment: XPath attribute syntax was *deprecated* in jQuery 1.2 as the release notes you link to state. It was only eliminated in jQuery 1.3. See the release notes for [jQuery 1.3](http://docs.jquery.com/Release%3ajQuery_1.3).

Comment: Here's to 10k rep, by the way :)

Comment: Thanks @yahelc! Your comments prompted me to fork this combobox for my project (https://github.com/jslayer/jquery-combobox)

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the `@` symbol. The selector syntax now follows the css selectors (I think @ is from xpath).

You can also simplify your selector:

```
$("li:not([dataType='optgroup'])", _dropDownListJQuery)
```

Edit: confirmed, [@attrName=attrValue] is xpath